# How can I render comment pager on the top and the bottom of the comments portion of the page

Tags: theming, 9, paging

When comments are numerous on a node and you have a high comments per page setting, you have to scroll a lot to get to the pager.
My users have requested pager at top as well as bottom of **the comments list** (not the top of the page) on a default node page.

To clarify

**Current page layout**

- Title
- Content
- Comments
- Pager
- New comment form

**The desired result is**

- Title
- Content
- Pager
- Comments
- Pager
- New comment form

I've done this in the past in Drupal 7, but I can't figure out what template to use in Drupal 9.

I tried this code in field--comment.html.twig, without success.

```
{% if pager %}
  {{ pager }}
{% endif %}
```

None of the other templates in my theme seem to render the pager either, but has to be somewhere.
I have Twig debugging on which provided some clues. I have checked page.html.twig, node.html.twig, and comment.html.twig as well as the field template. None of them seem to render the pager.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but obvious or not, I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pager can be duplicated in the field--comment.html.twig if you correctly identify the pager (which I did not in the question).

```
{% if comments.pager %}
 {{ comments.pager }}
{% endif %}
```

Tested in my custom theme and also in Olivero.